# Javascript prompt loads before page displays

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

I added a prompt on my page but it loads before the page has loaded.
How do I only show the message once the whole page is visible?

Here is my prompt:

```
if (name == null || name == "") {
  txt == "No name provided";
} else {
  txt = "Hello, " + name + "! How are you today?";
}
alert(txt);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wrap the code in an event-listener that listens for the `DOMContentLoaded` event it'll run only once the document is ready:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e)=>{
  if (name == null || name == "") {
    txt == "No name provided";
  } else {
    txt = "Hello, " + name + "! How are you today?";
  }
  alert(txt);
});
```

I have, however, adjusted your original code to:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
  // assign the name via the prompt() interface, and
  // declare both variables (rather than accidentally
  // creating globals):
  let name = prompt("Hi, what's your name?"),
      txt;
  // name won't be null, but it may be falsey, so here
  // we check if the name is falsey:
  if (!name) {
    // if the user cancels the prompt, prompt() returns
    // false; if they provide an empty-string that
    // empty string is falsey:
    txt = "No name provided";
  // if the name variable is truthy:
  } else {
    // we use a template literal String to interpolate
    // the variable 'name' into that string:
    txt = `Hello, ${name}! How are you today?`;
  }
  // I wouldn't recommend alert, but I left this unchanged:
  alert(txt);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/a8fc0nhq/).

References:

- [`alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert).
- [`DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt).
- [`Template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).
- [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window).

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad to have been of help! :)

Answer (score 2):

So to solve the problem of prompt loads before page displays:

- put your `script` tag just before the closing `</body>` not in the `<head>` tag.
- other option as *David Thomas* suggest is to listen to the **DOM** has been loaded with `DOMContentLoaded` & `addEventListener` or simply with `window.onload`.

Comment: It's an artefact of my original learning that I always place scripts in the head of the document, I *know* that placing it before the closing `</body>` tag solves the problem (arguably far more reliably), but I *never* think to do that. Anyway, long way of saying: thanks for reminding me, have a positive vote! :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest ways of doing this must be: `window.onload = alert("text");`. Also, consider placing the code just before the closing `body` tag or using an event listener of some kind for further control over the message display.